# Discord.py AFK Command Rewrite

Tags: python, python-3.x, command, discord.py, client

Here is my afk command:

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.mentions
    results = collection.find({"member": message.author.id}) 
    for result in results:
        collection.delete_one(result)
        if message.content == result:
            await message.channel.send(f"This person is currently AFK. \nFor: {reason}")
        

    await client.process_commands(message)
```

Error:

```
  File "main.py", line 124
    if message.mentions
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I was a little confused on why. any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the conditional colon `:`,

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.mentions:
        results = collection.find({"member": message.author.id}) 
        for result in results:
            collection.delete_one(result)
            if message.content == result:
                await message.channel.send(f"This person is currently AFK. \nFor: {reason}")
            

        await client.process_commands(message)
```